# Dynamically selecting tables in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query in mySQL

```
SELECT id FROM admin_products;
```

which return a list of ids, like so

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
```

And I was using PHP to dynamically generate tables like

```
vendor_1, vendor_2, vendor_3, vendor_4, vendor_5
```

Now I want to write a query to retrieve the `price` and `quantity` from the table `id`

**For example**

`"ENTER QUERY HERE"`

Should retrieve

```
+-----------------------------+
| id   | price   | quantity   |
+-----------------------------+
|    1 |       23|          13| // price and quantity retrieved from table vendor_1 since id=1
|    2 |      158|          85| // price and quantity retrieved from table vendor_2 since id=2
|    3 |       15|           7| // price and quantity retrieved from table vendor_3 since id=3
|    4 |      112|           9| // price and quantity retrieved from table vendor_4 since id=4
|    5 |      123|         199| // price and quantity retrieved from table vendor_5 since id=5
+-----------------------------+
```

What I'm doing now in PHP is:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pwd,$db);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM admin_products";
$res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $product = array();
        $innerSQL = "SELECT price,quantity FROM vendor_".$row['id'];
        $innerRes = mysqli_query($conn,$innerSQL);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($innerRes)>0){
            while($innerRow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($innerRes)){
                 array_push($product,$row['id']);
                 array_push($product,$innerRow['price']);
                 array_push($product,$innerRow['quantity']);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

But it takes two hits to the mySQL database. Can't it be reduced to one?

## EDIT

I have later on realized that my database structure was incorrect and dynamically creating tables is a very bad idea and could spell disaster later on

Comment: `dynamically generate tables` Well that sounds like a terrible idea

Comment: Ya I got to know that now. I'm new to database management and I am currently learning. So now that it's done it's done. Any solution to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### -Solution 1:

Note: This will only work if you have in your vendor_x tables id for the vendor id to match them with. (As Strawberry said, this is a terrible idea to dynamically generate tables).

After selecting the correct id you can do something like this:

- connect to the MySql Server

Then you can create the table name and store it in a variable.

```
$tableName = 'vendor_' . $id;
```

I would suggest after that to have a check if the table exists with a simple query:

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$tableName'";
```

If this returns empty result you can throw an exception that the table does not exist or handle it whatsoever way you would like.

After checking every table, to be sure it exists, you can create your query.

```
$joins = "";

$sql = "
    SELECT 
        v.id, 
        price, 
        quantity 
    FROM
        vendors AS v
";

foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $tableName = "vendor_" . $id;
    $tableAlias = "v".$id;

    $joins .= " LEFT JOIN " . $tableName . " AS ". $tableAlias ." 
                    ON (v.id = ". $tableAlias .".vendor_id) ";
}

$sql .= $joins;
```

Then execute the query.

### -Solution 2:

Create only one table to manage your vendors. It should have a structure like this :

```
`id` // AI value
`vendor_id` // The id of the vendor to easily join it afterwards
`price`
`quantity`
```

You can name it something like `vendor_product` or whatsoever

And now you have only one simple query:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        v.id,
        vp.quantity,
        vp.price
    FROM
        vendors AS v
        LEFT JOIN vendor_product AS vp
            ON (vp.vendor_id = v.id)
";
```

EDIT for the comment about the structure:

You will need one table for the vendors, such so:

```
`vendor`:
    `id`, //AI value
    `username`,
    `password` // I suggest to you not to keep it in plain text.

`vendor_product` :
    `id`, //AI value
    `vendor_id`,
    `price`,
    `quantity`
```

I don't know here if you are going to store more information about each product, but this should do the trick.

How to show the product with least price ?
You need to match them by somehow and group by that selecting minimum price.

Comment: I suggest Solution 2. Much more simple, clean, easy and fast without any overhead.

Comment: Yes solution 2 would do it nicely. But the problem is that each vendor has multiple products. How do I do that if I have only one table for vendors?

Comment: Your structure is wrong. You need to have one table for the vendors, one table for the products something like `product_id`, `vendor_id` and one more table for the product details where you list the price and quantity.

Comment: Ok I will briefly tell you my requirement. Hopefully you could guide me into structuring it correctly. **1.** I need to store all product details. **2.** I need to store vendor information like username and password. **3.** Multiple vendors maybe selling the same product at different prices and quantitites**4.** Only the vendor having least price should be displayed to the customer

Comment: Edited my question you can check it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll restructure my DB

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it suits

```
$table = "vendor"."_".$id; // this will create table name if $id = 1 then $table = vendor_1;
mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM $table");
```

**2nd**

If you want to fetch `data` of all `table` at once then

1)  fetch `id` from `admin_products` and store in an `array` like

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

2) Now loop throw `array` and create `sql`;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM "; 
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach($ids as $id){
$table = "vendor"."_".$id; // this will create table name if $id = 1 then $table = vendor_1;
$sql .=" $table,";

}
$sql = rtrim($sql,",");// this will trim the last comma
echo $sql;

// output SELECT * FROM vendor_1, vendor_2, vendor_3, vendor_4, vendor_5
```

Comment: So I would need 2 queries? One to retrieve the IDs and one to retrieve the price and quantity?

Comment: Yes that is kind of what I was doing. See my edited question